# Read Data from Excel(Row By Row) to Web in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automationanywhere

I Have Excel Sheet and I Want that it read data from Excel Sheet Row By Row And Put it in a web form (Automate) until and unless Excel Sheet Row not to an End

Answer (score 3):

your question is not very precise or you just have not look into AAE functions. The simplest way is to use loop as below:

[image]

Then assign each row to variable [image]

Don't forget to put "Excel Get All Cells" before starting loop.
[image]

Last step is to pass variable to web recorder which will place it in correct place.